# Matplotlib: data from DataFrame appears incorrectly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib, plot

I have a DataFrame with the price of the apartments and the number of rooms (living rooms, halls, bathrooms). I need to make a bar graph representing how price depends on the number of each room type.

My data appears, but it appears incorrectly. What exactly I do wrong?

```
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',') #read the dataset
dataFrame.replace('', np.nan)
#create new smaller dataset
roomsDF = pd.DataFrame(dataFrame[['Price', 'Living Rooms', 'Halls', 'Bathrooms']]) 
roomsDF = roomsDF.dropna(axis='rows')

#plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

plt.subplot(131)
print(roomsDF.head(300))
plt.bar(roomsDF['Living Rooms'], roomsDF['Price'], color='darkgreen')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.bar(roomsDF['Halls'], roomsDF['Price'], color='limegreen')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.bar(roomsDF['Bathrooms'], roomsDF['Price'], color='seagreen')

plt.savefig('Picture')
```

It definitely should appear in a rising manner (logically (and I've checked!) apartments with 1 living room is cheaper than with 2 living rooms), but it has a huge price for 1-room apartments.

Data is somethingk like that:
Average price for 1 living room should be ~659, for 2 l rooms ~1061 (counted in excel)
[Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7o7Me.png)

Graph is like that:
[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g8i1b.png)

Comment: What exactly are your data? How does the bar graph look like? Currently it seems to me that your data are wrong, because you do nothing with them, except plotting. Is the `read_csv()` giving the correct numbers?

Comment: @destructioneer Data is correct,  I've checked it. And other graphs seem to be correct (but I've made them through groupby). Maybe I'm putting data into plt incorrectly? I've posted pictures of my data and graph.

Answer (score 0):

It can be because of data types, you can try this updated code that I developed for you, but if I know what are the data or share a part of it I can help you better

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Read the dataset
dataFrame = pd.read_csv('dataset.csv', sep=',')
dataFrame.replace('', np.nan, inplace=True)  # Apply the NaN replacement to the DataFrame

# Create new smaller dataset
roomsDF = pd.DataFrame(dataFrame[['Price', 'Living Rooms', 'Halls', 'Bathrooms']])
roomsDF.dropna(axis='rows', inplace=True)  # Drop rows with missing values

# Convert columns to numerical data type
roomsDF['Living Rooms'] = pd.to_numeric(roomsDF['Living Rooms'])
roomsDF['Halls'] = pd.to_numeric(roomsDF['Halls'])
roomsDF['Bathrooms'] = pd.to_numeric(roomsDF['Bathrooms'])

# Plotting
plt.figure(figsize=(12, 4))

plt.subplot(131)
plt.bar(roomsDF['Living Rooms'], roomsDF['Price'], color='darkgreen')
plt.xlabel('Living Rooms')
plt.ylabel('Price')

plt.subplot(132)
plt.bar(roomsDF['Halls'], roomsDF['Price'], color='limegreen')
plt.xlabel('Halls')
plt.ylabel('Price')

plt.subplot(133)
plt.bar(roomsDF['Bathrooms'], roomsDF['Price'], color='seagreen')
plt.xlabel('Bathrooms')
plt.ylabel('Price')

plt.tight_layout()  # Adjust subplot spacing
plt.savefig('Picture.png')
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be a data type... I think everything is already numeric. Sorry, I can't paste data here because I don't know how to format it. But there are three columns 'Price', 'Living Rooms', 'Halls' and 'Bathrooms'.

Answer (score 0):

I needed to use `groupby` here as well. Without `groupby`, it was just showing some random things.

```py
plotData = pd.DataFrame(dataFrame.groupby(['Living Rooms'])['Price'].mean()).reset_index()
plt.bar(plotData['Living Rooms'], plotData['Price'], color='darkgreen')
```